# How to return success in a ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call to delete a page from my database, but I'm not quite sure how to return success and use it:

My ajax call looks like this:

```
$('.delete_button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'delete_page.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            page_id: id
        },
        succes:function() {
            alert('something');
            if (s.Err == false) {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        }, error:function(e){

        }
    });
});
```

And in my delete_page.php I have this:

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';    

$id = $_POST['page_id'];
$page_id = $id[0];

$delete_page = DB::getInstance()->delete('pages', array('id', '=', $page_id));

if ($delete_page) {
    $output['Err'] = false;
} else {
    $output['Err'] = true;
}

return json_encode($output);
```

It does delete the page, but it doesn't run the if statement and it is not alerting anything. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP script, you need to output the data instead of returning it:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```

Then in your javascript file you need to retrieve the data:

```
success: function (data) { // It's success not succes, and you need the parameter
    alert('something');
    if (data.Err == false) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the spelling that made the problem :)

Answer (score 6):

Dont use return, actually output the data, with the correct header:

```
//return json_encode($output);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer :)
Could you maybe explain me a little bit more about what the content type does?

Comment: Sure, it is just an http header. It tells the  client (your browser) what format the data will be in, in this case json. A normal html page will have a content type of text/html. See here for more details http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 0):

If that's the entire delete_page.php, it needs to `echo` the output, not just return it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more elegant way of handling this.

Update your **delete_page.php** script like this:

```
<?php

require 'core/init.php';    

$id = $_POST['page_id'];
$page_id = $id[0];

// Init
$output = array(
    'IsDeleted' = false,
    'LastError' = ''
);

// Delete
try {
    $output['IsDeleted'] = DB::getInstance()
                            ->delete('pages', array('id', '=', $page_id));
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    $output['LastError'] = $ex->getMessage();
}

// Finished
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Then update your ajax code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'delete_page.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        page_id: id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    succes: function(result) {
        if (result.IsDeleted) {
            window.location.reload(true);
        } else {
            alert('Failed to delete. Last error: ' + result.LastError)
        }
    },
    error:function(e) {
    }
});
```